# p2p connection library for Blockchain example

Tags: blockchain, javascript, p2p

I would like to implement the missing p2p communication for this [example repo](https://github.com/lhartikk/naivechain).

Does anyone know the best library I could use to implement communication between nodes? Moreover a tutorial or guide to understand communication between nodes in a blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many p2p networking implementation but [libp2p](https://github.com/libp2p) and [ÐΞVp2p](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-devp2p) are the most popular ones.

libp2p is used in [IFPS](https://ipfs.io/) where as ÐΞVp2p is used in [Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/). Both are well maintained and upto date p2p networking library and supports sub protocols to be developed on top of them.

Both have supported features like NAT traversal, encrypted streams, routing, peer discovery.

Going through the example code in their respective repositories is a good starting point.

Edited: [Here](https://github.com/nolash/go-ethereum-p2p-demo) are some sample programs for ÐΞVp2p go implementation.